# Busco SQLSRV php_pdo_sqlsrv_?????_ts.dll

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, xampp

Buen día estaba intentado conectar Xampp a SQL Server por medio de PHP pero me sale que no tengo instalado el controlador, entonces necesito saber si hay uno para la versión de PHP 7.3.1

Comment: La pregunta es: ¿Lo buscaste?

Comment: Error fatal : Error no detectado: Llamada a la función no definida sqlsrv_connect () en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ IVAMEX2 \ templatemo_491_flat \ conexion_sis.php: 4 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 {main} arrojado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ IVAMEX2 \ templatemo_491_ \ conexion_sis.php en la línea 4

este error me aparece
lo busque en las versiones mas recientes 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: lo busque aqui 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Para PHP 7+ necesitas la versión 4 del driver, [revisa este enlace](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Answer (score 1):

1- Descarga la extensión PHP SQL Server para la version de PHP que tienes
[PHP drivers Version 5.6.1 for SQL Server](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.1)
En tu caso es la `Windows-7.3`
Descomprimir y copiar los dos archivos de librería correspondientes (`php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll` y `php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll`) en `~\xampp\php\ext`

2- Editar `~\xampp\php\php.ini` y en la parte de las extensiones, incluir estas 2 líneas

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll ; MSSQL Server
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll ; MSSQL Server PDO
```

3- Descargar e instalar [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

Comment: Enlace del punto 1 roto.

Comment: @A.Cedano corregido.

Comment: Ok, -1 retirado. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui descargas todas las versiones
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]